# Meteor - Error: can't get arch with uname -p?

Tags: meteor

When I cd into the folder of a newly created Meteor app and run it with the 'meteor' command, I get

```
/Users/stylinchas/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_5.19pr45f.7esr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:218
  throw error;
  ^

Error: can't get arch with uname -p?
at run (/tools/utils/archinfo.js:151:15)
at Object.host (/tools/utils/archinfo.js:161:11)
at ProjectContext.reset (/tools/project-context.js:90:45)
at new ProjectContext (/tools/project-context.js:56:8)
at Command.doRunCommand [as func] (/tools/cli/commands.js:335:24)
at /tools/cli/main.js:1531:15
```

IF you have any ideas on why this is happening, I would appreciate your help - thx!

Comment: On which OS is this running?

Comment: On Mac High Sierra - 10.13.6 - thanks for your interest.

Comment: What does ```uname -p``` return when you run it on a console?

Comment: i386 after typing uname -p

Comment: Hey, I am having this issue, would be great if you posted a follow up

Comment: This is a dead end too. But, just linking it here for more context. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10716