# Meteor on MacOS "can't get arch with uname -p?"

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

After installing Meteor.js for MacOS, I try to create an app and I get an error related to 'uname -p'. The application is created, but I get the same error when trying to start the application.

**Recreation Steps**

`curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`

`meteor create app`

Output:

```
/Users/{user}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.4gwv5w.33478++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: can't get arch with uname -p?
    at run (/tools/utils/archinfo.js:151:15)
    at Object.host (/tools/utils/archinfo.js:161:11)
    at ProjectContext.reset (/tools/project-context.js:94:45)
    at new ProjectContext (/tools/project-context.js:60:8)
    at Command.func (/tools/cli/commands.js:769:24)
    at /tools/cli/main.js:1531:15
```

Then:

`cd app`

`echo "METEOR@1.8.1" >> .meteor/release`

`meteor`

Output:

```
/Users/{user}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.4gwv5w.33478++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: can't get arch with uname -p?
    at run (/tools/utils/archinfo.js:151:15)
    at Object.host (/tools/utils/archinfo.js:161:11)
    at ProjectContext.reset (/tools/project-context.js:94:45)
    at new ProjectContext (/tools/project-context.js:60:8)
    at Command.doRunCommand [as func] (/tools/cli/commands.js:337:24)
    at /tools/cli/main.js:1531:15
```

My output from `uname -p` is `i386`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Relevant source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/tools/utils/archinfo.js#L146) for those interested.

Comment: possibel dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414088/meteor-error-cant-get-arch-with-uname-p